# UV Mapping, XZY coordinates to UV coordinates

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, coordinates

I'm kind of new to this and found myself having issues wrapping my head around UV-mapping. (also not 100% sure if this is the correct forum for my question)

I am working on a small rendering engine (perspective software rasterizer) and I can't figure out the correlation between UV coordinates and XYZ coordinates. I'm using blender for modelling and exporting the vertices of the triangles via a python script, writing those as CSV and letting my engine read them in.

So far so good, I then tackled texturing those objects. Created UV maps in blender, worked, but I'm not sure how those are supposed to come into play. When rendering my models I'm solely accessing the vertices of the triangles of the object (XYZ). How does one get the corresponding UV coordinates?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I didn't find any literature about this. Or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: uv data is in the face loops, either in [bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html#customdata-access) or [object data](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.loops) uv points are between 0.0 and 1.0 and place the vertex on the source image, 0.0 being one side and 1.0 being the other.

Comment: @sambler aren't UV coordinates actually floats? They are desirably most often between 0 and 1 but can actually take any value like for tileable textures, right?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos yes uv's are float values. 0.0 is one edge of the image and 1.0 is the other, and 0.5 is the centre of the image. Values outside that are wrapped around, so 0.5 and 1.5 correspond to the same location on the image.